# visual studio cant see new project from existing code

Tags: visual-studio

I cant see this command in file menu. File->New->Project from existing files ...
there isnt it.

how can i customise visual studio to see it ?

thanks for help

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: It's a feature of VS 2010. Did not exist before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you have Visual Studio 2010 professionnal and above...

I see two options to bring back that menu!

1. [**Reset your settings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx)
2. Customize the File menu to add up the missing command (See [**To add a command to a menu or oolbar**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdee4yb6.aspx).

[image]

Comment: The latter didn't help. Resetting settings to default "General Development Settings" is the way to go. "Web Development" wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To make a project from existing source files: if you do not have a project for them yet you need to first make a new project. This will automatically make a ProjectName.CS file; you can simply delete this file in the Solution Explorer. Then right-click on the project folder, and choose "Add...." -> "Existing item", and choose the file or files you already have.

Answer (score 0):

To add an existing project to your solution, right click on the solution in the solution explorer, select `Add` -> `Existing Project...`.

If this isn't what you are asking, please clarify your question. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @gruber - Sorry, I still don't understand. An existing project? Adding existing files to a project?